Finding the number of binary search trees with specific conditions
Suppose that $V = \{a_1, a_2, \dots , a_{n-1}\}$ are the nodes of a binary search tree (BST) and $a_n$ is the final node of BST. We want to find the number of BSTs such that every node has exactly one child, except for the final node which doesn't have any child. For example take $V = \{10, 20, 60, 30\}$ and $a_5 = 50$. The possible BSTs are, $$V_1=\{60 , 10, 20 , 30 , 50\}, \\ V_2=\{10 , 20, 30 , 60 , 50\}, \\ V_3=\{10 , 20, 60 , 30 , 50\}, \\ V_4=\{10 , 60, 20 , 30 , 50\}.$$  Here is the diagrams of the BSTs:
$V_1:$
   60
  /
10
  \
   20
     \
      30
        \
         50

$V_2:$
   10
     \
      20
        \
         30
           \
            60
           /
         50

$V_3:$
   10
     \
      20
        \
         60
        /
      30
        \
         50

$V_4:$
   10
     \
      60
     /
   20
     \
      30
        \
         50

The interesting pattern is that if we denote the number of nodes which are greater than the final node by $k$, and denote the number of nodes except the final node by $n$, then the number of possible BSTs are $C(n,k)$. In this example only $60$ is greater than $50$, so $k=1$. Also $n=4$, so the number of desired BSTs is $C(4,1) = 4$. I don't know whether this pattern holds generally or it's accidentally.

Do we assume all the $a_j$ are distinct? Then it doesn't hurt to assume they are the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$ and can we formulate the problem as counting permutations $\sigma \in S_n$ s.t. for all $i$ either $\forall j>i: \sigma(j)>\sigma(i)$ or $\forall j>i: \sigma(j)<\sigma(i)$?

@ploosu2 After reviewing the question more closely, it seems that duplicate numbers are allowed.

Assume the numbers are $1,2,\dots, n$. (So in effect we're assuming just that all the numbers are distinct. It doesn't matter which particular numbers they are, just their order matters.)
Denote the count of those ending in $k$ by $b(n, k)$.
Let's take a BST ending in $k$ (and satisfying the condition).
Its first node must be either $1$ or $n$. (If $k \in \{1,n\}$ only one of these is possible.). This holds because the first node is the root. If there are both smaller and bigger numbers than it, it will have both left and right child.
Strip the first node away, and we're left with an instance with one node less (when in the first case we shift the numbers by $-1$, so $k$ becomes $k-1$). And this is bijective: each configuration (ending in $k-1$) makes a configuration (ending in $k$) when we put $1$ as the new root and increase all the other numbers by $1$ and also each configuration with $n-1$ nodes (ending in $k$) makes a configuration (ending in $k$) when we put $n$ as the new root. Hence for $n>1$ and $1<k<n$
$$
b(n,k) = b(n-1, k-1) + b(n-1,k)
$$
and the edge cases are $b(n,1) = b(n,n) = 1$ since then the BST must be just decreasing or increasing all the way.
This is the same recursion as the binomial coefficients (except starting from $n=1$) so we do indeed get
$$
b(n,k) = \binom{n-1}{k}.
$$

Thanks. Would you explain why the first node must be $1$ or $n$? Also I couldn't understand how the recurrence $b(n,k) = b(n-1, k-1) + b(n-1,k)$ is derived.

I added some explanations to the answer. The first node must be $1$ or $n$ because otherwise the root will have both children present. And the recursion comes basically because those two cases partition the configurations into two parts and each part is in bijective correspondence with a set of configurations with $n-1$ nodes (ending in $k-1$ in the first case and ending in $k$ in the second).

Thanks. Now I understand the recurrence relation but unfortunately I have difficulty in understanding the other question. Specifically, I don't know how to prove that choosing a different root other than $1$ or $n$ leads to the conclusion, i.e., root will have two children.

It's because in BST all the nodes in the left sub tree need to be smaller than the root and all the nodes in the right sub tree need to be bigger than the root. If the root is strictly between $1$ and $n$, then the number $1$ will be in the left sub tree and $n$ in the right. So in particular both are non empty and hence the root has both children present.

But the presence of duplicate numbers is another problem. Hmm.. this is just a quick guess, but could it be that we multiply the answer by $2^D$ where $D$ is the number of duplicates. Because for each duplicate it can be either left or right child of its parent.

Very nice, thanks. In fact we use this fact until we get to the cases where the final node is minimum or maximum of the numbers. In these cases only one BST can be constructed and we are done.
